# NoReverseMatch at /products/ , 'products ' is not a registered namespace

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm making 2 apps in Django. The first one is called "products" and the second is called "blog". 
I made the first one and everything was working correctly, but when I added the second one, both didn't work

**urls.py**

```
path('products/', include('products.urls')),
path('blog/', include('blog.urls')),
```

**blog\urls.py**

```
app_name = 'articles'
urlpatterns = [
   path('<int:id>/', article_detail_view, name='article_detail'), ]
```

**products\urls.py**

```
app_name = 'products'
urlpatterns = [
   path('<int:id>/', product_detail_view, name='product_detail'), ]
```

More details about the code:
src> blog : { templates > articles > article_create.html and article_detail.html and article_list.html , forms 
, models , urls , views } , products  { templates > products > product_create.html and product_detail.html and product_list.html , forms 
, models , urls , views }

article_create.html and product_create.html contain same code :

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<form method="post"> {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" , value="Save">

</form>
{% endblock  %}
```

blog\models :

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

class Article(models.Model) :
    title = models.CharField(max_length=130)
    content = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    active= models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
       return  reverse("articles : article_detail",kwargs={"id":self.id})
```

blog\urls :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

from blog.views import (
    article_detail_view,
    article_create_view,
    article_list_view,
)
app_name = 'blog'
urlpatterns = [


    path('<int:id>/', article_detail_view, name='article_detail'),
    path('create/', article_create_view, name='article_create'),
    path('', article_list_view, name='article_list'),

]
```

blog\views :

```
from django.shortcuts import render , get_object_or_404 , redirect
from django.views.generic import CreateView , DeleteView , DetailView , ListView , 
UpdateView
from .models import Article
from .forms import ArticleForm


def article_detail_view(request,id):
    obj=get_object_or_404(Article,id=id)
    context = {
        'object' : obj
    }
    return render( request , "articles/article_detail.html" , context )


def article_create_view(request):
    form=ArticleForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        form = ArticleForm()
    context = {
        'form' : form
    }
    return render( request , "articles/article_create.html" , context )


def article_list_view(request):
    queryset = Article.objects.all()   #list of objects
    context = {
'object_list' : queryset
}
return render( request , "articles/article_list.html" , context )
```

INSTALLED_APPS contain 'products' and 'blog'

I put the same code with changes of course for the product file(products\urls and product\views...)

I wish i made it clear for you right now .

Comment: Did you add `products` to the `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: Yes i did and the blog app too ; as i said the products app works correctly before i added the blog app .

Comment: Can you share your project file tree? Or at least the relevant part for the issue? That might give us a hint.

Comment: Okay I edited this post putting more details.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is, for the app **products** your namespace is default to 'products', but for the app **blog** you are using specifying app as 'articles'

the app_name should be actual name of your app

```
app_name = 'blog'
urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:id>/', article_detail_view, name='article_detail'), ]
```

Comment: Did you try to add namespace parameter in the include()

Comment: No; how can i do that?